# How to Convert Runnable .jar File to Native Code?

Tags: java, native, runnable

I wrote a Signer Application (it can sign with smart cards) as runnable jar. I want to run it without a java VM. How can I do this? I tried ExcelsiorJet, but it didn't sign without error.

How can I convert my runnable jar to native code?

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the place for software recommendations. You're on the right track, though. What you're looking for is a Java native compiler like Excelsior. However, note that there are few products to choose from. An alternative is to use a programming language which can run on the JVM, but can also be compiled to native code. Such a language exists!

Comment: what is the name of the language ?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa: If there aren't that many options, there isn't that much space for opinions. So the question remains: how can it be done?

Comment: I apologize wrongly,
How can I do that?

Comment: Converting to a native application is something you probably want to just give up on. Instead, consider using the Java 9+ feature of using jlink. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: Sorry , my application can run only  java 8 version.

Comment: The constraint to use only older versions, such as Java 8, is relevant when targeting those older JVMs (for example, JVMs installed at client sites where you don't have access to upgrade them). If you are looking to turn it into a native executable, why on earth are you concerned about the version of Java? Just go and use Java 11 and JLink!

Answer (score 1):

Check the GraalVM, it could convert java bytecode to native images.

https://www.graalvm.org/docs/examples/java-kotlin-aot/